# How to represent "&nbsp;" as a delimiter for Scanner

Tags: java, regex

Trying to parse this simple string into two `float` variables turns out to be less trivial than I initially thought:

```
-0.13 0.17%
```

The (only?) reason is that the space between the two numbers is actually a `&nbsp;`. So the first `scanner.next()` returns the **entire** string:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("-0.13 0.17%");
String first = scanner.next();
```

I know of Scanner's [useDelimiter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) method, but how do I tell it to use `&nbsp;` as a delimiter?

I tried `useDelimiter("&nbsp;")` but that didn't work

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default delimiter for `Scanner` class is `\p{javaWhitespace}+`. [`\p{javaWhitespace}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is defined by the method [`Character.isWhitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28int%29), which excludes non-breaking spaces by definition.

> Determines if the specified character is white space according to Java. A character is a Java whitespace character if and only if it satisfies one of the following criteria:
>
> - It is a Unicode space character (`SPACE_SEPARATOR`, `LINE_SEPARATOR`, or `PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR`) but is not also a non-breaking space (`'\u00A0'`, `'\u2007'`, `'\u202F'`).
> - `[...]`

If you want to include No-Break Space, which is `'\u00A0'`, **and** also the default Java whitespaces, you need to construct a regex that combines them together:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("[\\p{javaWhitespace}\u00A0]+");
```

Note that the `+` behind is important. It causes the whole pattern to match against a **consecutive** sequence of whitespaces. Without this, `next()` will return empty string when there are consecutive whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Ampersand escape sequences only work in HTML and XML, not in Java. Try instead using `"\u00a0"`.

Comment: This works! Thanks. But I also tried `useDelimiter("\\s")` and it works too. So now all of a sudden I have 3 different ways that work. :) Which one is best?

Comment: @RegexRookie: `\\s` should NOT work, unless the string doesn't contain a no-break space.

Answer (score 2):

Ascii of 160 is nbsp, so concatenate a char with that value with your string and it should work.

```
char nbsp = 160;
useDelimiter("" + nbsp);
```

Comment: @Taymon Actually this one works for me too (in addition to your `"\u00a0"` suggestion). Which is better?